# How do I mutate the item in Iterator::find's closure?

Tags: rust, libusb

I would like to use `Iterator::find` on [`libusb::Devices`](http://dcuddeback.github.io/libusb-rs/libusb/struct.Devices.html) object, which has a signature like so:

```
fn find<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item> 
    where Self: Sized, P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool
```

I want to find a device with a particular `vendor_id`, which requires calling [`Device::device_descriptor`](http://dcuddeback.github.io/libusb-rs/libusb/struct.Device.html#method.device_descriptor) on each device. However, the `device_descriptor` method requires a `&mut` to each device, and the find method only gives a `&`.

Does this mean that it's impossible to use mutable methods on any of the Iterator's methods (`find`, `filter`, etc.)?

Here's the example I'm trying to get working:

```
let mut device = context
    .devices()
    .unwrap()
    .iter()
    .find(&mut |dev: &libusb::Device| { 
         dev.device_descriptor().unwrap().vendor_id() == vendor_id
     })
    .unwrap();
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*dev` as mutable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean that it's impossible to use mutable methods on any of the Iterator's methods (`find`, `filter`, etc.)?

In the methods that receive a parameter of type `F: Fn*(&Self::Item)`, yes. One cannot call a method that expects a mutable reference (`&mut`) on a reference (`&`). For example:

```
let mut x = vec![10];
// (&x)[0] = 20; // not ok
(&mut x)[0] = 20; // ok

//(& (&x))[0] = 20; // not ok 
//(& (&mut x))[0] = 20; // not ok
(&mut (&mut x))[0] = 20; // ok
```

Note that this rule also applies to auto deref.

Some methods of `Iterator` receive a parameter of type `F: Fn*(Self::Item)`, like `map`, `filter_map`, etc. These methods allow functions that mutate the item.

---

One interesting question is: Why do some methods expect `Fn*(&Self::Item)` and others `Fn*(Self::item)`?

The methods that will need to use the item, like `filter` (that will return the item if the filter function returns `true`), cannot pass `Self::Item` as parameter to the function, because doing that means give the ownership of the item to the function. For this reason, methods like `filter` pass `&Self::Item`, so they can use the item later.

On the other hand, methods like `map` and `filter_map` do not need the item after they are used as arguments (the items are being mapped after all), so they pass the item as `Self::Item`.

---

In general, it is possible to use [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) to replace the use of `filter` in cases that the items need to be mutated. In your case, you can do this:

```
extern crate libusb;

fn main() {
    let mut context = libusb::Context::new().expect("context creation");

    let mut filtered: Vec<_> = context.devices()
        .expect("devices list")
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|mut r| {
            if let Ok(d) = r.device_descriptor() {
                if d.vendor_id() == 7531 {
                    return Some(r);
                }
            }
            None
        })
        .collect();

    for d in &mut filtered {
        // same as: for d in filtered.iter_mut()
        println!("{:?}", d.device_descriptor());
    }
}
```

The `filter_map` filters out `None` values and produces the wrapped values in `Some`s.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Another option that might work in some situations is iter_mut(), but unfortunately libusb doesn't implement it.

Comment: In general, `iter_mut` produces `Item = &mut T`, so `&Item = &&mut T`. That means that the filter function cannot mutate the item... See https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f01e4c90f80a777c10f01e217e29f739&version=stable&backtrace=0

Answer (score 1):

Answer migrated from: [How can I apply mutating method calls to each struct when using Iter::find?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70251163/4038191)

You can use [`Iterator::find_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find_map) instead, whose closure takes in elements by *value* which can then be easily mutated:

```
games
    .iter_mut()
    .find_map(|game| {
        let play = rng.gen_range(1..=10);
        game.play(play).then(|| game)
    })
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8cde088cbce0c5dc7e1657c29c2e1324)