# How can I apply mutating method calls to each struct when using Iter::find?

Tags: rust

My code is below, and [also on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fb0e8906dd8ef9efde5c63b93868c26e).

```rust
use rand::Rng;
const THRESHOLD: i32 = 50;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Game {
    plays: Vec<i32>
}

impl Game {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            plays: vec![]
        }
    }

    /// A game wins when the sum of all plays exceeds the threshold 
    fn play(&mut self, play: i32) -> bool {
        self.plays.push(play);
        self.plays.iter().sum::<i32>() > THRESHOLD
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Build the games
    let mut games: Vec<Game> = Vec::new();
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    for _ in 1..10 {
        games.push(Game::new());
    }

    // Play the games & find a winner
    loop {
        if let Some(winner) = games
            .iter_mut()
            .find(|game| {
                let play = rng.gen_range(1..=10);
                game.play(play)
            }) {
                println!("Winner!: {:?}", winner);
            }
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like `game.play(play)` inside the predicate given to `find` saying:

```
`game` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

My attempts to dereference `game` have only further offended the borrow checker. What is the idiomatic way to call a mutating method **inside** a find predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Iterator::find_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find_map) instead, whose closure takes in elements by *value* which can then be easily mutated:

```
games
    .iter_mut()
    .find_map(|game| {
        let play = rng.gen_range(1..=10);
        game.play(play).then(|| game)
    })
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8cde088cbce0c5dc7e1657c29c2e1324)

Comment: I'd encourage you to move your answer to the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620491/mutate-item-in-iteratorfind)

Comment: @Shepmaster done, thanks for the suggestion!